# Zsh function with su and echo

Tags: shell-script, zsh, quoting

I'm trying to add a function to my `.zshrc` that makes adding new USE flags to my `/etc/portage/package.use` file easier. Normally, I'd have to do

```
su -c 'echo "net-misc/aria2 bash-completion bittorrent" >> /etc/portage/package.use'
```

So I tried making a function like

```
new_use() {
    su -c 'echo "$1" >> /etc/portage/package.use'
}
```

but then I realized it wouldn't work. I want to know if there's a way of making this function work, or at least if functions are appropriate for this. By the way, I don't mind having to type the root password every time I call the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse the quotes.

```
new_use() {
    su -c "echo '$1' >> /etc/portage/package.use"
}
```

This will cause `$1` to be expanded before the execution of `su`.

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: This is probably good enough here, but beware that in general, this is unsafe because it allows the caller of the function to execute arbitrary shell commands by passing an argument that contains a single quote (`' >/dev/null; echo evilhacker.example.com >>/root/.rhosts; : '`).

Comment: @Gilles it requires the _root_ password.

Comment: @jordanm Which is why it's probably good enough here. But it's not a stretch to extend that to a `sudo` rule, or to a script that doesn't verify its arguments. Many security holes come from chaining two steps that are safe individually but not in combination. It's better to keep protected at every step.

Answer (score 7):

You can feed stdin to a program with root privileges, like so:

```
new_use() {
    sudo tee -a /etc/portage/package.use <<< "$1" > /dev/null
}
```

Comment: Wow, that comes handy. Thanks for the alternate answer!

Comment: Gotta love unix. I don't think I've ever seen three '<<<' before 8-).

Comment: @slm, it's a shell feature known as a [here string](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_strings).

Answer (score 3):

The argument of the function is not passed to the underlying shell. You can substitute the argument inside the string that `su` will pass to the root shell, but beware that the string will be parsed by the root shell, so special characters in it will be expanded. To avoid this extra expansion (which could cause arbitrary code to be executed as root), interpolate the string between single quotes (which causes all characters other than `'` to be interpreted literally), and protect single quotes characters in the string (`'\''` terminates the string literal, appends a single quote, and starts a new literal, which means that `'\''` is effectively a way to put a single quote inside a literal delimited by single quotes).

```
new_use() {
  su -c "echo '${1//\'/\'\\\'\'}' >> /etc/portage/package.use"
}
```

Another possible approach is to [use `tee`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/zsh-function-with-su-and-echo/60415#60415).

Comment: Very interesting. So that means you can use single quotes inside single quotes, and your function would be used like `new_use 'net-misc/aria2 bash-completion bittorrent'` instead of using double quotes, right?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can “use single quotes inside single quotes”, but the single quote has to be written `'\''`. What you write is a valid use of the function, but it could equivalently be written `new_use "net-misc/aria2 bash-completion bittorrent"` or `new_use net-misc/aria2\ bash-completion\ bittorrent` or many other ways.

Comment: Oh, I know you have to escape them if you want to use single quotes inside single quotes. But then I don't think I understand your answer. What makes it different from the others, besides avoiding the extra expansion? Sorry. bash syntax still manages to confuse me.

Comment: @user1002327 See [my comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60411/zsh-function-with-su-and-echo/60471#comment83655_60414) under jordanm's answer: the problem is when there's a single quote in the argument.

Comment: Oh, I'm terribly sorry, I hadn't read it before commenting here. Well, the accepted answer is more than enough in this case, but I'll take your advice into account. Didn't know you could do that.